# How to create such a button group?

Tags: android, xml, layout

I am new to android programming and want to have such a button group:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/4x3l797iwgdaha1/2013-02-20%2020.12.57.png

I tried to create such a layout via the Dashboard-Layout (from the Google IO) but it doesn't look like this, because there is a higher distance ("margins" in a dashboard.

Has anyone a suggestion how to create a "ButtonGroup"-Layout like you see on the screenshot?

Thanks in advance!

knickelbert

Comment: That looks like a simple 2x2 GridView where each item has an ImageView on the left and two TextViews on the right. What have you tried?

Comment: The GridView looks interesting. Do I need Java-Code to get items into an GridView or is it possible to design a static, XML-only GridView?

Comment: GridView a subclass of ListView, it is set up in a similar way. You can design the item's layout in XML, Java, or a mix of both. You'll probably need to write a basic custom Adapter to work with your custom layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `android:padding` and `android:gravity` as when fit to requirement to `TableLayout`.

---

```
 <TableLayout 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
 android:stretchColumns="2"
 android:shrinkColumns="2"
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <TableRow>
   <ImageButton 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:src="@drawable/ursrouce"
    />
  <ImageButton 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:src="@drawable/ursrouce"
    />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
    <ImageButton 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:src="@drawable/ursrouce"
    />
   <ImageButton 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:src="@drawable/ursrouce"
    />
   </TableRow>
 </TableLayout>
```

---

You can add  horizontal and vertical separator as when required after `<ImageButton>`

Vertical ::

```
<View
     android:layout_width="1dip"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
     android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
     android:background="#FF0000FF"
     />
```

Horizontal ::

```
<View
     android:layout_width="fill_parent "
     android:layout_height="1dip"
     android:background="#FF0000FF"
     />
```

Comment: That looks promising. I took your code and added two textviews as described by Guarav Arora but is there a way to tell android to put a textview under another in a table layout? I've done this before with  android:layout_below="..." but that doesn't seem to work in a table layout!

Comment: @knickelbert : You need `RelativeLayout` to use relativity of below, above. . . with reference to `id`. So put your `TableLayout` inside `RelativeLayout` gives some `id` to it. Then reference your `TextView` unders `TableLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make this generic format, you can use a TableLayout with Two Rows and each row having two columns else a gridview with number of columns set to 2 can also give you the similar appearance.